# Custom Field in Query for MS Access Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, iif

I am trying to put a custom field in a query. My other 2 have come off without a hitch, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am missing to get this one to work. I've tried dozens of different permutations of code. I am trying to take either DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT]) if there is anything in that column, or DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS]) if there is not. With the caveats that if there is anything in [Green_Date] it should return "" and if the value in [REV_PRM_DT] is 01/01/2055 it should return "" (we use this as a filler to get it to not show up other places).

I'm hoping I'm pulling a stupid and missing something obvious.[Showing incorrect behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6piF.png)

Some examples of things I have tried are:

Days to ATS:iif(([REV_PRM_DT]<>"01/01/2055") and ([Green_Date] is null),iif(([REV_PRM_DT] is not null),DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT]),DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS])),"")

Days_to_ATS:iif(([REV_PRM_DT]<>"01/01/2055") and ([Green_Date] is null),iif(([REV_PRM_DT] is not null),DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT]),DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS])),"")

Days_to_ATS:iif([Green_Date] is null,iif([REV_PRM_DT]="01/01/2055","",iif([REV_PRM_DT]="",DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS]),DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT]))),"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume these fields are date/time data type. Since expression should return a number value, don't return `""`, return `Null` or 0. Use # instead of quote for date delimiter. More parens than needed.

```
IIf([REV_PRM_DT] <> #01/01/2055# AND [Green_Date] Is Null, 
   IIf(Not [REV_PRM_DT] Is Null, DateDiff("d", Date(), [REV_PRM_DT]), DateDiff("d", Date(), [X65-SCHATS])), 
   Null)
```

or simplified

```
IIf([REV_PRM_DT] <> #01/01/2055# AND [Green_Date] Is Null, 
   DateDiff("d", Date(), IIf(Not [REV_PRM_DT] Is Null, [REV_PRM_DT], [X65-SCHATS])), 
   Null)
```

`Is Null` is SQL operator. `Nz()` is VBA function but can be called in Access query. Calling VBA function can slow performance but likely not noticeably.

```
IIf([REV_PRM_DT] <> #01/01/2055# AND [Green_Date] Is Null, 
   DateDiff("d", Date(), Nz([REV_PRM_DT], [X65-SCHATS])), 
   Null)
```

Because of `AND` operator, REV_PRM_DT must be <> #01/01/2005# **and** Green_Date must be Null in order to calculate DateDiff - if you want calc when either case is true, use `OR`. Maybe this is what you need:

```
IIf([REV_PRM_DT] = #01/01/2055# OR Not [Green_Date] Is Null, 
   Null,
   DateDiff("d", Date(), Nz([REV_PRM_DT], [X65-SCHATS])))
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on the # vs. ". Taking a bit of one of the fields that was working properly and melding it with one of your suggestions, I came up with: ```Days_to_ATS:iif([REV_PRM_DT]<>#01/01/2055# and [Green_Date] is null,IIf(Not [REV_PRM_DT] Is Null,DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT]),DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS])),Null)``` We only want the DateDiff run if both the green date is empty and rev_prm_dt is not in the "parking lot" (1/1/2055). The issue is still persisting, though where it works fine so long as there is something in the Rev_PRM_DT. If it's empty, it stays blank.

Comment: Doing some testing:
    `Days_to_ATS: IIf([REV_PRM_DT]<>#01/01/2055#, "Not A Problem", "Problem")`
This is behaving as if REV_PRM_DT = 01/01/2055 even when it's empty. Not sure how to overcome this one. Nor why it isn't doing it in the CHAARV field. They're both set to date types, but the field referencing that one is behaving just fine:

    `Receipt_to_ATS_(Days): iif([CHAARV]<>#09/09/9999# and [Green_Date] is null,IIf(Not [REV_PRM_DT] Is Null,DateDiff("d",[CHAARV],[REV_PRM_DT]),DateDiff("d",[CHAARV],[X65-SCHATS])),Null)`

Comment: I got it to work! Many thanks, June7! I'm not sure why part of it wasn't behaving properly, but reversing it appears to have worked just fine:
    `Days_to_ATS: IIf([REV_PRM_DT]=#01/01/2055# OR NOT [Green_Date] Is Null,Null,IIf([REV_PRM_DT] Is Null,DateDiff("d",Date(),[X65-SCHATS]),DateDiff("d",Date(),[REV_PRM_DT])))`

so checking to see if it = 1/1/2055 OR green date is not null and reversing the outputs for the true/false part of the IIF seems to have it behaving itself now. Thank you very much for the tip about # instead of " and the adjustment to utilizing null as opposed to "".

Comment: Glad it works. But why not the simplified DateDiff() expression? Why not use Nz()?

Comment: Mostly because I understood how the long-hand way worked and didn't feel like I had time to look into the not zero function as I've never used it before. I will probably go through and update it after the rest of the project is finished, as I love learning new things. There was a serious time crunch involved in this portion for the VP of the company. Truth be told, I left it a little late to ask for help. I'm not used to not being able to brute force it myself, lol. I'm much more familiar with Excel, but he wanted it converted to Access and I haven't played in Access since 2014 or so.